# Serial port project form close not responding

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to make serial port based project i have code like this .when i try to close my form it become not responding and hang my app please give suggestion and correct my mistakes in my code thank you in advance

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class frmMain
    Dim bw As BackgroundWorker
    Dim myPort As Array  'COM Ports detected on the system will be stored here
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String) 'Added to prevent threading errors during receiveing of data

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadLine())    'Automatically called every time a data is received at the serialPort
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
        'compares the ID of the creating Thread to the ID of the calling Thread
        If Me.Label1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.BeginInvoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.Label1.Text = ([text] / My.Settings.deci)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
      
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SerialPort1.PortName = My.Settings.comport          'Set SerialPort1 to the selected COM port at startup
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = My.Settings.baud
        'Set Baud rate to the selected value on 

        'Other Serial Port Property
        SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
        SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8            'Open our serial port
        SerialPort1.Open()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Try closing the port in `frmMain_FormClosing`?

Comment: Diagnose deadlock with Debug > Break All + Debug > Windows > Threads.  You'll probably see one of them executing inside SerialPort1_DataReceived(), waiting for an end-of-line character that never comes.  When you use SerialPort.ReadLine() then it is important to set the SerialPort.ReadTimeout property.

Comment: What Hans told you is the main problem, you should also call `Close()` in the `FormClosed` handler. Also, all that stuff in `ReceivedText()` is not needed: remove `SetTextCallback()` and the rest in `ReceivedText()` and just `BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() Label1.Text = "Some Text"))`. What is this thing: `([text] / My.Settings.deci)`? Are you expecting text or what? Set `Option Strict On` before anything else, it will help a lot.