# How to take data from weight scale to my software in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I tried code like below to access the serial port but when I tried to close my form it hung and the software stopped responding.

```vb
    Imports System
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.IO.Ports

    Public Class frmMain
        Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String) 'Added to prevent threading errors during receiveing of data

        Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
            ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadLine())    'Automatically called every time a data is received at the serialPort
        End Sub

        Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
            'compares the ID of the creating Thread to the ID of the calling Thread
            If Me.Label1.InvokeRequired Then
                Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
                Me.BeginInvoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
            Else
                Me.Label1.Text = ([text] / My.Settings.deci)
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            SerialPort1.PortName = My.Settings.comport          'Set SerialPort1 to the selected COM port at startup
            SerialPort1.BaudRate = My.Settings.baud
            'Set Baud rate to the selected value on 

            'Other Serial Port Property
            SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
            SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
            'Open our serial port
            SerialPort1.Open()
        End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have anything in the form unload event?  You show where you open the serial port, do you ever close it?

Comment: I tried to close serial port in closing event but I got I/O error in my code on ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadLine()) this line what I have to do to close problem

Comment: See the notes and sample code in [SerialPort.ReadTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout). This was already explained, along with some more info, in [your previous (identical) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64573461/7444103) -- Remove that `SetTextCallback`.